# If no title is given error message appears in the wrong color

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, usability

[screenshot http://img686.imageshack.us/img686/6418/wrongcolor.png](http://img686.imageshack.us/img686/6418/wrongcolor.png)

---

This is easily "fixed" by changing the class of the error message from `form-item-info` to `form-error`. The error message will be much more visible, and more in sync with the others:

[alt text http://img638.imageshack.us/img638/9903/formerror.png](http://img638.imageshack.us/img638/9903/formerror.png)

Comment: Actually those error messages need to be `font-size:3em;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just moved most of the post validation to the server, so any submission errors can be simplified and placed in the same area on the form:

http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/6915/stackoverflowserverside.png